# Insert into select in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

Is there any way in Django ORM to execute **insert into select** statement.

```
# Django models
class FileSet(models.Model):
    use_case = models.ForeignKey("UseCase", related_name="file_sets")

class TrainingFileSet(Base):
    file_set = models.ForeignKey(FileSet, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

```
INSERT INTO TrainingFileSet (file_set_id)
SELECT id
FROM FileSet
WHERE use_case_id=1;
```

Comment: It may be possible in a slightly different way via the ORM, add your models to the question

Comment: Added the models @IainShelvington

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't do it directly, but can use `bulk_create`  to perform the operation fast enough for most cases:

```py
id_list = FileSet.objects.filter(file_set_id=1).values_list('id', flat=True)
TrainingFileSet.objects.bulk_create([TrainingFileSet(file_set_id=id) for id in id_list])
```

If it's not efficient enough you can always run the sql code directly: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly